# Google Sheets Script for automatically sorting table based on multiple columns - ERROR

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to come up with a Google Sheets Script for automatically sorting a table based on multiple columns. I got the auto sorting to work, and then decided I would like the sheet to be updated only when I reached column 6 of each row. This way, the new rows would not be updating with each entry and moving like crazy. Instead, it would be sorted once filling it was completed. However, the table is not sucessufuly updating. After getting this working, I would also like to apply the rule to the Individual02 sheet, so that when that one is update it also gets sorted automatically, and would also love some help with this step. I am a super beginner so learning a lot, I appreciate all the help.

This is the link to the table, if you would like to create a copy to run tests: [text](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IG9dtrJWVuMBbOVprhOVWnBiuCg-yv4sjD_4gdwo_po/edit?usp=sharing)

**This is the script I have, does anyone have any suggestions?
**

```
// created this first part so that the values can be easily changed as they are referenced in the Part 02, where the function is. This way I could share the Script with other people and all they would have to do is change this first part's values to match their own table.

// Part 01 - Defining Variables:

var SHEET_NAME = "Individual01"

var DATA_RANGE = "A2:G999" // from Column A Row 2 (excluding top row bc it is the header) to Column G row 999 

var SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 3, ascending: true}, // sorted by Category
{column: 4, ascending: true}, // then sorted by Status
{column: 5, ascending: true}, // then sorted by Priority
{column: 1, ascending: true}, // then sorted by Title
{column: 6, ascending: true} // then sorted by Together?
]  // ascending order = true, and descending order = false

var SORT_COLUMN_NUMBER = "6" // function will be activated after the cell in this column is filled
var FIRST_ROW_AFTER_HEADER = "2"


//________________________________________________________________________//
// Part 02 - Writing the Function for Multi Sorting Columns:


// Part 02-a
function autoSortMultiColumns(e){
  
  
    const row = e.range.getRow() // saving the row value from our range
    const column = e.range.getColumn() // saving the column value from our range
    const ss = e.source // spread sheet
    const currentSheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
    const currentSheetName = currentSheet.getSheetName

    if (!(currentSheetName === "SHEET_NAME" && column === SORT_COLUMN_NUMBER && row >= FIRST_ROW_AFTER_HEADER)) return 
    // The update will only happen after the sort column has been filled.

    const range = currentSheet.getRange(DATA_RANGE)
    
    range.sort(SORT_ORDER) // uses the variable defined in part 01

    ss.toast('Sort complete.')
}


// Part 02-b
function onEdit(e){ // onEdit(event)special function that runs everytime something changes in your spreadsheet

  
  autoSortMultiColumns(e) 

}
```